# how do I convert an integer which is defined in an int array to hex?

Tags: c++

I have an int array that represents a very large number such as:

```
// ...
unsigned int n1[200];
// ...

n1 = {1,3,4,6,1,...} ==> means my number is 13461...
```

How can I convert that large number to its hex value?

Comment: Do you mean the hex value as a string?

Comment: Where is the hexadecimal involved...

Comment: for example, my number is 55. that means it will be located in my int array like this : n1[0]=5 , n2[1]=5. now i want to find the hex value of 55 which is 37 (that s what i need). my number may be very large. if i made some mistakes when i was explaning, sorry about my english or explanation :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So here is my take on the problem:

1. You have an array of digits.
2. You want to build an unsigned int from this array of digits.
3. The array of digits could be either HEX digits, or DECIMAL digits.

To build this unsigned long long, assuming an array of DECIMAL digits:

```
unsigned long long myNum = 0;
unsigned int n1[200];

for (int i=0; i < n1.length ; i++ ){
    myNum += pow(10,i) * n1[n1.length - i];
}
```

To build this unsigned long long, assuming an array of HEX digits:

```
for (int i=0; i < n1.length ; i++ ){
    myNum += pow(16,i)* n1[n1.length - i];
}
```

(Notice the base 16)

*Disclaimer: limited to exactly 16 digits MAX stored in your array. After that you will overrun the buffer*

If it is just a matter of DISLAYING the number in the correct format...

Well, an int is an int is an int... (in memory).

There are 10 fingers on my hands whether or not I call that number 10, or A.

If you want to format the number for DISPLAY in hex, then try something like:

```
unsigned int i = 10;
//OR
unsigned int i = 0xA;

printf("My number in hex: %x", i);
printf("My number in decimal: %d", i);
```

Comment: The `^` operator is actually the bitwise exclusive-or operator. You need to use something like `pow()` to perform that type of operation.

Comment: @dreamlax: Thanks for the catch. It was sort-of pseudo coded, but good call nonetheless.

Comment: Your solution shows how to represent a large hex number using a similar scheme to the OP's.  However, conversion between the two schemes is different.  Remember that `9 * pow(16,3)` is not equal to `9 * pow(10, 3)`.

Comment: @Thomas: I believe that is the point. The two schemes are supposed to be different. He wants to rebuild a unsigned int from an array of digits. But he wants to imagine that the array of digits represent hex digits, not decimal.

Comment: The question says "very large number".  I don't think passing a single `unsigned int` to `printf` will handle that.

Comment: for example, my number is 55. that means it will be located in my int array like this : n1[0]=5 , n2[1]=5. now i want to find the hex value of 55 which is 37 (that s what i need). my number may be very large. if i made some mistakes when i was explaning, sorry about my english or explanation :)

Comment: @Buzzinga: the method I've posted will allow you to do this up to exactly 16 digits if you use a "unsigned long long" to store the value.

Answer (score 0):

I'm unsure if you want the hexadecimal represented as a string. If that's
the case, here's some code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stack>
using namespace std;

string toHexa(int num){
    string digit = "0123456789ABCDEF", numStr = "";
    stack<char> s;

    do {
        s.push(digit[num%16]);
        num /= 16;
    } while (num != 0);

    while (!s.empty()){
        numStr += s.top();
        s.pop();
    }
    return numStr;
}

int main(){
    int num = 235; // EB in hexa
    cout << num << " to hexadecimal: " << toHexa(num) << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Nice tutorial: [Converting decimal to hexadecimal](http://www.permadi.com/tutorial/numDecToHex/).

Comment: I doubt that will work for a "very large number" as described in the question.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [GMP library](http://gmplib.org/manual/index.html) to make this relatively straightforward.

- Use `basic_stringstream<unsigned int>` to wrap your array.
- Use `operator <<` to read it into a `mpz_t` variable.
- Create another `basic_stringstream<unsigned int>` for your result.
- Use `std::hex` and `operator >>` to write the variable back out in hexadecimal.

That would work on ASCII digits, but yours aren't.  You can still use GMP, but you'll want to use the `mpn_get_str` and `mpn_set_str` functions instead.  You'll need to copy your digits into an `unsigned char[]` and then you can specify the base for conversion to `mp_limb_t` and back to a string of digits.